# Can't create generic javax validator for Enum only

Tags: java, validation, generics, enums

I'm trying to define a validation annotation for Enum fields as generic as possible (i.e. working only on Enum field type, and for all kind of Enum).

The goal is to have an annotation that will authorize only some values within the enum.

I created the annotation this way:

```java
@Target({ FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { EnumRestreintValidator.class })
public @interface EnumRestreint {
    String message() default "The field value is not included in the authorized values.";

    String[] authorizedFields() default {};

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Then the validator:

```java
public class EnumRestreintValidator<T extends Enum<T>> implements ConstraintValidator<EnumRestreint, T> {

    Set<T> validFields;

    @Override
    public void initialize(EnumRestreint constraint) {
        validFields = Arrays.stream(constraint.authorizedFields()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(T enumValue, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return false; // Not implemented yet
    }
}
```

Exemple of use:

```
@EnumRestreint(authorizedValues = { "BANANA", "APPLE" })
private Fruits value; // validator should break if value == Fruits.ORANGE
```

I want to access the annotated field enum without including the enum class in the annotation parameters. So I tried to make the validator generic.

But I get this compilation error on the annotation definition:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = { EnumRestreintValidator.class })
// Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<EnumRestreintValidator> to Class<? extends ConstraintValidator<?,?>>
```

**Is it possible to use a generic validator as I'm intending to do? Or am I forced to pass the enum type in annotation parameters?**

Comment: Try looking at https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validations-enums

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've succeeded to create a decorator that can validate that an Enum variable has a value within a given range of the Enum value.

See on [github gist](https://gist.github.com/Kapcash/d69deb8d123882cf7e34c35552acf91d).

```java
// EnumRestreint.java

@Target({ FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { EnumRestreintValidator.class })
public @interface EnumRestreint {
    String message() default "The enum value is not included in the possibles values.";

    String[] authorizedFields() default {};

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

```java
// EnumRestreintValidator.java

/**
 * Restreint possibles values from Enum
 */
public class EnumRestreintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EnumRestreint, Enum<?>> {

    /** The possible values you can pick from the parameterized enum */
    Set<String> validFields;

    @Override
    public void initialize(EnumRestreint constraint) {
        validFields = Arrays.stream(constraint.authorizedFields()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Enum<?> enumValue, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return validFields.contains(enumValue.name());
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not really working out if you want to validate a parameter, but only rather to restrict the possible values of an enum. at runtime, it will first try to convert the input to an Enum<?> and only then call your validator. it only works if you did input a valid entry form the enum, otherwise would crash before entering your validator

Comment: Thank's for your answer, this is so bloody tricky!